# How do I implement this pop up box that displays when hovered over "Shopping Cart" link in this website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I want exactly like this...not a simple box but the one with shadow borders like this one..I have been googling but all I came across is Slide down boxes and tool tips..that's not what I want..How do I implement the one in this website..oh and this box's got HTML stuff in it...like buttons and all

Is there any way I can see the code of this in that website ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [clueTip jQuery Tooltip Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#getting-started)

There are also many [stylish Tooltip Plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) in which you have options to style it in your favorite style.